# How do i avoid generating html in a java custom tag handler?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags, custom-tag

Every example i can find has the tag handler java class generating html and spewing it out with `out.print(someHTML);`

Is there a way to include a jsp and add attributes to the request instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this but it should be possible by [obtaining a RequestDispatcher](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) from the Request object:

```
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    try {
        pageContext.setAttribute("title", "My Title");
        pageContext.getRequest().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/includes/header.jspf").include(pageContext.getRequest(), pageContext.getResponse());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
}
```

The PageContext also has an [include](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#include%28java.lang.String%29) method but that seems to only work for static files, not jsps.

Comment: Just an update for this - setting attributes on pageContext doesn't work you need to do it on the request scope & it's necessary to do a .flush() before using the request dispatcher or the output doesn't get included int he right place. Mind if I update your answer?

Comment: @BedwyrHumphreys: Go ahead, thats the spirit of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Try a JSP custom tag file; here's a simple example using an attribute.

Tag files have to live under WEB-INF/tags, so in WEB-INF/tags/makebold.tag:

```
<%@ attribute name="toBold" required="true" %>

<b>${toBold}</b>
```

In boldtest.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="my" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<my:makebold toBold="this will be bolded" />
```

I read up on tag files [here](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/jserverpages3_ch11/index.html) and [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/11/14/tagfiles.html).