# Avoid generating html in a Java custom tag handler, part 2

Tags: java, servlets, jsp-tags

I have run into a wall trying to find an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693065/how-do-i-avoid-generating-html-in-a-java-custom-tag-handler) on how to avoid generating HTML within a custom tag handler.  Like this questioner, I'm trying to avoid a bunch of `println()` statements in my tag handler, and I'd really like to pull in the data from another .jsp file.

Accordingly, I tried the method suggested:

```
public int doStartTag() throws JspException {
    try {
        pageContext.getResponse().flushBuffer();
        pageContext.getRequest()
                .getRequestDispatcher("/views/tags/loginBlock.jsp")
                .include(pageContext.getRequest(), pageContext.getResponse());
    } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }

    return EVAL_BODY_INCLUDE;
}
```

What I'm getting, however, is the content of loginBlock.jsp *above* the output of the jsp in which the tag is located, not inserted in place of the tag like I expected, even with the call to `flushBuffer()`.

I have a questions that I'm trying to get answers to, but the gods of Google aren't kind to me tonight:

1. If I need to insert a block of HTML from a tag handler, is this the best way to do it?
2. In the original answer, the poster uses a classic tag handler.  Is there some way to do it using simple tag handler (that is, in a class that extends SimpleTagSupport) instead?
3. Even though the questioner in the question liked above accepted an answer, I'm not able to duplicate successful results.  Am I missing something that the questioner picked up on that I'm leaving out?
4. Am I just way off base here in some way I'm not even aware of? I'm kind of new to the whole jsp/servlets thing, and I'm not 100% sure this design pattern is what I should be using. I'm basically trying to design jsp files that call back-end Java that performs some business logic and generates resultant HTML, but like I said above, I don't want to stick a bunch of `println()` calls in my Java tag handlers.

Thanks for any help and/or insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woot, I finally found a better answer, and I *knew* I had to be overlooking something probably relatively simple and fairly obvious.  There's another version of `include()` that takes a boolean as a second parameter.  [According to the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/jsp/PageContext.html#include%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29):

> If flush is true, The current JspWriter "out" for this JSP is flushed as a side-effect of this call, prior to processing the include. Otherwise, the JspWriter "out" is not flushed.

So my original code above should be in a class that extends SimpleTagHandler, and should be this instead:

```
public void doTag() {
    PageContext context = (PageContext)getJspContext();
    try {
        // The second parameter below (true) causes the JspWriter to be flushed
        context.include("/views/tags/loginBlock.jsp", true);
    } catch (Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
}
```

Not only is that much shorter and simpler, but it means that I don't have to go putting buffer="none" in all of my JSP page directives.  If anyone else runs across this question and answer, I hope you find it useful, because it sure caused me a bunch of grief.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I found *an* answer, but I don't know if it's the *best* answer.  I inserted buffer="none" into the page directive of my master jsp page, and now the secondary jsp page falls in line where it's supposed to.  Again, I don't know if it's the best answer though, as it seems to me that I should be able to buffer the page.  I'll leave the question open for a few days in case someone has a better suggestion.